# Optimization of magento website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.8

I am using *magento 1.8.1* and it is very slow. I want to optimize this, for that I am using some free module for *HTML*, *CSS* and *JS* minification but its doesn't work.
After using that it create lots of error. I've referred website such like after merge JS, the custom module in front-end is stop working. I've checked lots of tutorial also for gzip compression and enabling Mod_deflect, I've followed all the step like put some code in `.htaccess` page like

```
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
 </IfModule>
```

But that also didn't work.

this is my website: [**Link**](http://www.littlebees.com)

Please help me into this.

Comment: What are your server specs? Are you just using Magento's caching system? Maybe try swapping it out of APC, or memcached? Try tweaking your PHP config and MySQL config, and potentially swap out apache for nginx or varnish? There's lots of things you can do to help improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has the option to merge css and js files which works for me. I minimise the css and js files I use but I DON'T minimise the standard Magento files (epsecially prototype. I've read that this can break things).

As for compression, it's possible that you can't use the standard htaccess approach. See [Compressing js & css files where mod deflate not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876371/compressing-js-css-files-where-mod-deflate-not-available) for a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to merge CSS and JS byon the admin panel `System > Configuration > Developer` (Be careful with the JS, the site stop working right in my case).
- The thing that change everything for me it's changing the cache module. Magento use a cache module witch use the *Zend_Cache library* and create a huge numbers of files that makes the site terrible slow. You can easy replace it with this:

  [Cm_Cache_Backend_File](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_File)

  or even better, magento is prepeared to work with [Redis](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-performance/1640-connecting-magento-with-redis-by-unix-socket). With this feature the cache goes to RAM instead the File System.

   Good luck!